# MVC2 Routing and Security: How to securely pass parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, query-string, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm a relative MVC noob coming from WebForms. I think I have a pretty good grasp of MVC with a couple exceptions, and I think I may have broken the pattern. I'm gonna try to keep this short, so I'm assuming that most of what I am asking is relatively obvious.

Let's say I have a news site with articles. In that case, a URL in the form of mynewssite.com/Articles/123 works just great because I don't care who views which article. The user can change the ArticleID in the URL to whatever they want and pull up that article. In my case, however, I only want the user to be able to view/edit data entities (articles, or whatever) that belong to them. To achieve this, I am using their UserID (GUID) as a foreign key in the database, and displaying a list of their data for them to choose from. Here comes the problem... when they click on the link that is created by Url.Action("Edit", New With {.id = item.id}) (I'm not using ActionLink because I need to add HTML content inside the link), the id shows up as a querystring parameter. I could add a route for it, but the id would still show up in the URL for them to tamper with. The obvious implication is that by tampering with the URL, they could view/edit any entity that they want.

What am I missing? 
Is there a good way to pass the parameters without adding them on the URL? I know that I could put them in a form on the page and submit the form, but that seems cumbersome for my example, and I'm using jQuery.ajax in places that seems to conflict with this idea.
I could also check their UserID against the data in the Edit method, but that also seems cumbersome, too.

Is this question too broad? Please let me know what specifics you need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even in Winforms, you would have to add special logic on each request to filter only the articles that the user owns.  I don't see why MVC should be any different.  Sure, you can use web.config to deny access to given url's, but not when you use a single page that takes a parameter of what data to show.

Your best bet is probably to filter this at the database level.  By adding a where clause that includes the user id, then the app will return a "no records found" sort of error, and you can do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [forms authentication](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs). This way when the user authenticates an encrypted cookie will be emitted which will contain his username which cannot be tampered with. Then you could verify whether the currently connected user has authorizations to edit this article.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using forms authentication. I just don't think I should have to check if the user has permission for this data on every request. Maybe it's because I'm used to WebForms where I can just secure a folder (with FA) and be done with it. My main question is what is the MVC best/standard way of passing parameters in this type of situation. I want to make sure I'm using MVC in the right way.